# Reversing for loop causing system errors

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, crash

This feels like a newbie issue, but I can't seem to figure it out. I want to iterate over the items in a std::vector. Currently I use this loop:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++) {
    myclass* var = buffer.at(i);
    [...]
}
```

However, I realised that I actually want to iterate over it in the opposite order: starting at the end and working my way to 0. So I tried using this iterator:

```
for (unsigned int i = buffer.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    myclass* var = buffer.at(i);
    [...]
}
```

But by simply replacing the old line with the new (and of course, recompiling), then it goes from running properly and iterating over the code, it instead causes the program to crash the first time it hits this line, with this error:

http://i43.tinypic.com/20sinlw.png

Followed by a "[Program] has stopped working" dialog box.

The program also returns exit code 3, according to Code::Blocks, which (if [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381.aspx) is to be believed) means ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND: The system cannot find the file specified.

Any advice? Am I just missing something in my for loop that's maybe causing some sort of memory issue? Is the return code of 3, or the article, misleading, and it doesn't actually mean "path not found"?

Comment: First of all, have you tried running it in a debugger? It will help you pinpoint the exact location of the crash, and will let you examine variables to see what might have cause it. Secondly, in the second loop, is the size larger than zero?

Comment: How will -1 be accessed with an `unsigned int` index? It's accessing more like `2**32-1`, e.g.

Comment: I really should have run it in the debugger, huh? Damn, this is what happens when you start coding on several days' sleep-deprivation...

Comment: Also, I know the size is larger than 0 because I check

`if (!buffer.empty())`

first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `i == 0` (i.e. what should be the last iteration), the decrement `i--` causes `i` to wrap around to the largest possible value for an `unsigned int`. Thus, the condition `i >= 0` still holds, even though you'd like the loop to stop.

To fix this, you can try something like this, which maintains the original loop logic, but yields a decrementing `i`:

```
unsigned int i;
unsigned int size = buffer.size();
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    i = size - j - 1;
```

Alternatively, since `std::vector` has `rbegin` and `rend` methods defined, you can use iterators:

```
for(typename std::vector<myclass *>::reverse_iterator i = buffer.rbegin(); i != rend(); ++i)
{
    myclass* var = *i;
    // ...
}
```

(There might be small syntactic errors - I don't have a compiler handy)

Answer (score 3):

An unsigned integer is always >= 0.  Furthermore, decrementing from 0 leaps to a large number.

Comment: Of course. How did I miss that? So is the problem just a stack overflow of sorts? It's just going through the loop ad infinitum... No wait. It's looping around to about 4 billion, and buffer.at(MAX_INT_VALUE * 2) (since it's unsigned int) is causing memory errors... So what would you suggest for an end condition?

Comment: @drummerp If `buffer` is a standard container, you can use iterators instead, for example a reverse iterator using `rbegin` and `rend`.

Comment: @drummerp just use int i or long i

Comment: for (unsigned int i = buffer.size(); i > 0; i--) {
    myclass* var = buffer.at(i-1);
}
(same thing the GNU reverse iterator does, actually :p)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I probably should, but to be frank, they confuse me in how they're used. I come from Java, and for some reason I just can't wrap my head around them. I should probably go try looking them up, though...

@P.R I prefer to use `unsigned int` because otherwise I get warnings about "comparison of signed and unsigned integer" or some such.

Comment: @Corbin Huh. I think that's probably the easiest suggestion I've heard so far, and still works. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I would suggest not using numeric types that have a large discontinuity near the important value zero, except when you require their special properties (for doing arithmetic that requires pure binary numbers without overflow, representing bitfields, etc.)

Comment: In all honesty @drummerp, you should just hunker down for 10 minutes and learn iterators.  If you can understand the standard containers, then you can understand iterators.  They are a bit odd at first glance, but they are extremely useful, and there are somethings with the containers that you cannot do without iterators (use <alogrithm> for example)

Comment: @Kaz I'm afraid I don't really understand what you mean. I'm sort of a newbie programmer still, it would seem. And I'm sleep-deprived right now, unfortunately... Explain please?

Comment: @Corbin Yeah, I know I should. I intend to at some point, once I can fit time around a million bugs that need fixing. Yeah, it's the programmer's fallacy, but still... I will eventually, though.

Comment: @drummerp I mean that the unsigned numbers are very useful. For instance you can add an unsigned int and an unsigned int, and never worry about overflow since they follow "wrapping arithmetic". They are good for checksum calculations, hashing, bitfields, simulating the arithmetic of different kinds of computers, etc. What unsigned integers are not good for are most situations when you just want computer integers which behave somewhat like mathematical integers. You want numbers that decrement below zero in the usual way that a test like `n >= 0` test does what it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> buffer = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    for (vector<int>::reverse_iterator it = buffer.rbegin(); it != buffer.rend(); it++) {
        //do your stuff
    }
    return 0;
}
```